# Express Request and Response types - Property does not exist on type

Tags: node.js, typescript, express

When I attempt to use either the Request or Response types like this:

```
app.use('*', (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
    res.set('Cache-Control', 'no-store');

    const requestId: string = req.headers['bearer']
      ? req.headers['bearer']
      : uuid.v4();

    (req as any).locals = {
      requestId,
    };

    next();
  });
```

I get the following errors:

`Property 'set' does not exist on type 'Response<any, Record<string, any>>'.`

`Property 'headers' does not exist on type 'Request<ParamsDictionary, any, any, ParsedQs, Record<string, any>>'.`

Here is another example:

```
app.post(`/login`, (req: Request, res: Response) => { console.log(req.body) });
```

And I get this error:

`Property 'body' does not exist on type 'Request<ParamsDictionary, any, any, ParsedQs, Record<string, any>>'.`

This error occurs *anywhere* I use the Request or Response model from express and **only when I attempt to start the application locally** via `npm start`.

Here is how I am importing the Request and Response models:

```
const express = require('express');
import { Request, Response, NextFunction } from 'express';
```

Here are the package.json:

```
{
  "name": "login-server",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc --sourcemap",
    "build-prod": "tsc",
    "start": "tsnd --respawn  src/index.ts",
    "lint": "tslint --fix --project tsconfig.json",
    "test": "jest",
    "test:watch": "jest --watchAll --runInBand --detectOpenHandles",
    "test:coverage": "jest --coverage",
    "precommit": "./node_modules/.bin/npm-run-all --parallel lint test"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "12"
  },
  "main": "lib/index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/supertest": "^2.0.10",
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "connect-redis": "^4.0.4",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "express-locals": "^1.0.1",
    "express-session": "^1.17.0",
    "express-validation": "^3.0.5",
    "firebase": "^7.9.3",
    "firebase-admin": "^8.6.0",
    "helmet": "^3.23.3",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "redis": "^3.0.2",
    "supertest": "^6.1.3",
    "ts-node": "^8.10.1",
    "tsconfig-paths": "^3.9.0",
    "uuid": "^3.3.2",
    "xss": "^1.0.7"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/express": "^4.17.2",
    "@types/express-session": "^1.17.0",
    "@types/jest": "^25.1.3",
    "@types/jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.0",
    "@types/node": "^13.7.4",
    "husky": "^4.2.5",
    "jest": "^25.1.0",
    "npm-run-all": "^4.1.5",
    "pm2": "^4.4.0",
    "source-map-support": "^0.5.19",
    "ts-jest": "^25.2.1",
    "ts-node-dev": "^1.0.0-pre.49",
    "tslint": "^5.12.0",
    "typescript": "^3.2.2"
  },
  "husky": {
    "hooks": {
      "pre-commit": "npm run precommit"
    }
  }
}
```

What I have already tried:

1. Matching the `express` and `@types/express` versions
2. Remove node modules and package-lock.json and re-installing via `npm install`
3. Clearing the npm cache via `npm cache clean --force` and then re-running item 2 ^^^

Here is a codesandbox recreating the issue: https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/quizzical-platform-9hmytx?welcome=true

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are mixing two different ways of importing the express module and its types.

Try the following:

```
import express, { Request, Response, NextFunction } from 'express';
```